# JQuery Mobile copy selected option to other dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Please help!

I've created a form where the user can input their address and their invoice address. If they select a checkbox their main address should all be copied over to the invoice address. This is working fine except one of the options is a drop down list, I've managed to get it working BUT only when I don't use JQM - It should copy the selected answer to the second drop down list (see in js fiddle - remove jqm and it works!).. I can't seem to find the issue with this. Any ideas?

```
$("#copyToInv").click(copyAdd);
                 function copyAdd()
                 {  

                     var add1=$("#custAdd1").val();
                       var add2=$("#custAdd2").val();
                        var add3=$("#custAdd3").val();
                         var town=$("#custTown").val();
                          var county=$("#custCounty").val();
                           var postcode=$("#custPostcode").val();


                       if (this.checked==true)

                            $("#invAdd1").val(add1);
                            $("#invAdd2").val(add2);
                            $("#invAdd3").val(add3);
                            $("#invTown").val(town);
                            $("#invCounty").val(county);
                            $("#invPostcode").val(postcode);
                            $('#invCountry').val($('#custCountry').val());
                                $('#invCountry').attr('selected', true);        

                }
```

Js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Gdn/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/b2Gdn/2/

#### JavaScript:

```
$("#copyToInv").click(copyAdd);

function copyAdd()
{   

    var add1=$("#custAdd1").val();
    var add2=$("#custAdd2").val();
    var add3=$("#custAdd3").val();
    var town=$("#custTown").val();
    var county=$("#custCounty").val();
    var postcode=$("#custPostcode").val();


    if (this.checked==true)

    $("#invAdd1").val(add1);
    $("#invAdd2").val(add2);
    $("#invAdd3").val(add3);
    $("#invTown").val(town);
    $("#invCounty").val(county);
    $("#invPostcode").val(postcode);
    $('#invCountry').val($('#custCountry option:selected').val());
    $('#invCountry').selectmenu('refresh', true);

}
```

#### Changes:

```
    $('#invCountry').val($('#custCountry option:selected').val());
    $('#invCountry').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer - this doesn't keep the selected answer from the first dropdown, it seems to just refresh the full list?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, take a look now

Comment: thanks that's perfect!! Do you know if there is a way to make it only change when the check box is "checked" rather than on click? Thanks